# How do I depend on another package when writing a package for Meteor

Tags: meteor, package

I am writing a package for my own Meteor App. I need to depend on a package named 'urlify' since it is not cover my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your smart.json, you can use `packages` indicate dependancies. (for mrt to work)

```
{
  "name": "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",

  "packages": {
    "urlify": "0.1.0"
  }
}
```

in your `package.json` indicate dependancies for meteor.

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.use(['urlify'], ['client', 'server']);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have made it. It works well. But it needs to mrt add urlify first, then mrt add myPackage. if I mrt myPackage before urlify, it throw an exception that can't find package urlify. can't automatically find urlify and install like collection2 depends on simple-schema.